# Add Language colors for the repositories using REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, api, github

I wanted to display all repositories of a username using REST API, so I want to get the language color as it is showing on Github.

e.g

[image]

I did display the total stars, forks, and language. But I want to display the language badges as well.
I hope I explained enough to understand.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET','https://api.github.com/users/murtazajafari/repos?per_page=3' , 
    true)
    request.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(data);
        var statusHTML = '';
        $.each(data, function(i, status){
            statusHTML += '<div class="card"> \
                <a href=""> \
                    <div class="col-auto"> \
                        <i class="fa fa-github"></i> \
                    </div> \
                    <h4>' + status.name +  '</h4> \
                    <div class="state"> \
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-star mr-2"></i>' + status.stargazers_count +  '</span> \
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-code-fork mr-2"></i>' + status.forks_count + '</span> \
                        <span class="repo-language-color mr-1" style="background-color:' + site.data.colors[status.language]["color"] + '"></span><span itemprop="programmingLanguage">' + repository.language + '</span> \
                    </div> \
                </a> \
            </div>';
        });
        $('.repositories').html(statusHTML);
    }
    request.send();
```

Comment: you have all the [colors in this repo](https://github.com/ozh/github-colors/blob/master/colors.json)

Comment: Yes, but how can I display that in my repository loop?

Comment: it's a json... just load it and use it... [I would do something like this](https://jsbin.com/simewon/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: if you want to be fancy: https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/vYOWzNa?editors=1010 :)

Comment: Thank you very much, can I have it in my code not using VueJS.

Comment: just adapt... it's almost the same

Comment: Is it possible to edit my code in order to have the language badge?

Comment: just use fetch for both, wrap in a `Promisse.all` call and execute ... can't be simpler. I hate messing up javascript and markup... before Vue I used [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender), but I never messed things like you are doing ... it will be so hard to change anything next time you want to update the code ... separation of concerns if one of the best methods a coder should be proud to implement :) the simplest of ways as your using jQuery, use `getJSON` for the colors file and api instead of `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple Google search returns several repos with the data you want, the one I selected was https://github.com/ozh/github-colors and the source code has a simple JSON file that you can load, just the way you're loading the GitHub API...

I will use `fetch` as it's simpler and as I stated to hate writing HTML as well... here's a simple solution:

```css
.color {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(repo, idx) in repos" :key="idx">
        <span class="color" :style="{ background: languageColor(repo.language) }">&nbsp;</span>
        {{ repo.language }} | 
        <a :href="`https://github.com/${repo.full_name}`">{{ repo.name }}</a> | 
        {{ repo.stargazers_count }} | 
        {{ repo.forks_count }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      repos: null,
      colors: null
    }
  },
  created() {
    var _ = this
    var urlApi = 'https://api.github.com/users/murtazajafari/repos?per_page=10'
    var urlColors = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ozh/github-colors/master/colors.json'

    fetch(urlApi)                    // fetch API data
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => _.repos = json)  // append to repos
    fetch(urlColors)                 // fetch colors data
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => _.colors = json) // append to colors
  },
  methods: {
    languageColor(language) {
      return this.colors[language].color // pick up the right color by language
    }
  }
})
```

live on [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/simewon/2/edit?html,js,output) and using Veutify on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/vYOWzNa?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I created a repo with the data you want. It fetches from [GitHub Lingustic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/linguist/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml). fetch the data from this [API](https://github-lang-deploy.herokuapp.com/) and use it. If you are trying to show your GitHub cards in Reactjs watch this [repository](https://github.com/sabesansathananthan/react-github-repo-cards) made by me.